# Unable to disconnect socket connection on app closure [React native]

Tags: android, react-native, websocket, socket.io

I have been working on a app where I need to list down currently active users. So, basically, i am started a socket connection on app creation and joining a room and emitting events from the backend whenever someone enters or leaves the app. But the problem here is when someone force kill the app through recent apps menu, the socket connection is not getting closed and as the result of it, if the user is reopening the app before 30 seconds of killing it, the previous socket is still open and the user is visible as active but after 20-30 seconds, the previous socket connection of the killed instance of the app gets closed and the final state is that the user is on the app but is inactive.

If I could somehow run some code right before the app gets closed, the problem would be resolved.

I tried several methods to solve it, first I looked at the AppState library by react native, but it happens that they don't provide the kill event for android apps.
I also tried out the onDestroy lifeCycle method of native code in java in android folder, but there was no success there as well, onCreate, onPause, onResume methods work perfectly but onDestroy is not being called.